# $(u,\mathrm{A}v)=\int_{-1}^{1}u^*(x)\frac{d}{dx}[(x^2-1)\frac{d}{dx}v(x)]dx=(\mathrm{A}u,v)$

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives, definite-integrals, sturm-liouville

I want to demonstrate that the following operator is a self-adjoint operator in $L^2(-1,1)$
$$(u,\mathrm{A}v)$$
$$\mathrm{A} =u^*(x)\frac{d}{dx}(x^2-1)\frac{d}{dx}v(x)$$

$$w=a+ib$$
$$w^*=a-ib$$

I want the proof of the following equality step by step.
$$(u,\mathrm{A}v)=\int_{-1}^{1}u^*(x)\frac{d}{dx}[(x^2-1)\frac{d}{dx}v(x)]dx=(\mathrm{A}u,v)$$
I'm stuck at the beginning.
$$(u,\mathrm{A}v)=\int_{-1}^{1}u^*(x)\frac{d}{dx}[(x^2-1)\frac{d}{dx}v(x)]dx=\int_{-1}^{1}u^*(x)\, 2x\, \,v''(x)\, dx$$

Thank you so much for the generous help.

Answer (score 2):

Integrating by parts, with $U=u^*$ and $V=(x^2-1)\frac{dv(x)}{dx}$ reveals

$$\begin{align}
(u,Av)&=\int_{-1}^{1}u^*(x)\frac{d}{dx}\left((x^2-1)\frac{d}{dx}v(x)\right)dx\\\\
&=-\int_{-1}^1 \left(\frac{d}{dx}u^*(x)\right)\left((x^2-1)\frac{dv(x)}{dx}\right)\,dx\\\\
&=-\int_{-1}^1 \left((x^2-1)\frac{d}{dx}u^*(x)\right)\left(\frac{dv(x)}{dx}\right)\,dx\tag 1\\\\
\end{align}$$

Then, integrating by parts the right-hand side of $(1)$ with U=$(x^2-1)\frac{d}{dx}u^*(x)$ and $V=v(x)$ yields

$$(u,Av)=\int_{-1}^1 v(x)\frac{d}{dx}\left((x^2-1)\frac{d}{dx}u(x)\right)dx=(Au,v)$$

as was to be shown!

Comment: (+1) This time, you had the faster fingers!

Comment: @Chappers ..."I'm not dead yet."  And thank you for the (+1)!  Much appreciative.  Not sure if you got the obscure movie quote reference??